# How to solve certificate failure in Python app running on Heroku?

Tags: python, ssl, heroku

I've got a python script, that scrapes some information from a site. It runs on my local PC without problems, but when I run it on heroku, the error is appearing:

`<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)>`.

Python's version on my local machine is 3.4.4 and python's version on heroku is 3.5.1, maybe it is the source of the error?

Here is the part of the code, that causes the error:

```
cj = CookieJar()
opener = build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
req = Request("url_here", headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla'})
html = opener.open(req)
```

So, how can this error be solved? Thanks.

Comment: What's the CA that's signed the cert for your `url_here`?  Is it a well-recognized trusted CA, or one that maybe you've specifically configured your system to trust, but which a generic Heroku container won't trust?

Comment: It was trusted by default on my local machine. I didn't do any manipulations with configurations.

Comment: Visit the URL in chrome. Between the "Home" icon and the URL, there is a little "Page" icon. Click on that, and click "Certificate Information". On the opened window, hit the right tab (Which is the certification path). What is the top Certificate in that tree? The reason we are asking is that you could have visited the site in the past and installed the SSL as a trusted CA. Even if you didn't do any script manipulations, it could have changed your environment.

Comment: On the top is "thawte".

Comment: So maybe we can somehow add this certificate to heroku app? Or create some kind of exception for this site? Are there any ways to solve this problem?